# Error in setDefaultClusterOptions(type = .sfOption$type) :could not find function "setDefaultClusterOptions"

Tags: r, snow, snowfall

I'm new here. I've been struggling with analysing some data with the **BaSTA package**, the data works ok after running the "Datacheck" code , but right after running the following code this happens:

```
multiout <- multibasta(object = datosJ, studyStart = 1999, studyEnd = 2018, model = "LO", 
             shape = "simple", niter = 20001, burnin = 2001, thinning = 100,
             parallel = TRUE)
   
No problems were detected with the data.

Starting simulation to find jump sd's...  done.

Multiple simulations started...

**Error in setDefaultClusterOptions(type = .sfOption$type) : 
  could not find function "setDefaultClusterOptions"**
```

I believe this error has something to do with the usage of "parallel = TRUE" which is a function of the snow package that comes incorporated in the BaSTA package and makes the analysis run faster. If I don't use parallel the analysis takes weeks in running  and I've been told that's not normal for the package I'm using.

Any help would be very helpful, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I came across this same behavior when using another R package that depends on snowfall. `setDefaultClusterOptions` is housed within a dependency of `BaSTA` so this is error message is because packages are not being loaded. Try calling `library(snowfall)` prior to running the BaSTA package command to see if that fixes it for you.

Comment: Hey, thank you. The snowfall package had already been called by that time. Somehow I managed to runned but now the analysis is taking way too long, something is not working because I was told it should take 2 minutes.